# ASP.Net Core 2.1 preview1 HTTP Error 502.5 Process Failure

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to enable the event log. But Microsoft's instructions for Administrative Tools > Event Viewer are not clear to me.

In addition to this other resources online say to add the following line to Web.config. The problem with this is that I don't have a Web.config. The default ASP.Net Core 2.1 Web API template does not come with one.

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyWebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```

How am I supposed to see the event log or enable stdoutLogEnabled="true" without a web.config.

[image]

Please help this is driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally referencing "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" version 2.1.0-rc1-final. I changed my rc1 version to the latest preview version with "Include prerelease" ticket. Changing from rc1 fixed my issue.

However I am unable to explain why using rc1 was giving me this issue.

In addition, please note that I am using prerelease as a personal preference (since this is a greenfield project). However I suspect you can keep "Include prerelease" off and select the latest non rc1 versions.

I hope this helps anyone else that runs into this annoying issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please use .net core version 2.0.6 and you will be fine, it is the most stable release as we speak. Version 2.1.2 appears to be a working progress.